How to auto boot and auto reset ESP32 Native USB (CDC)?
I'm trying to design a custom board with ESP32-C6 and don't want to use BOOT or RESET buttons.
Can someone point me to a reference schematic that shows how to enable auto boot / auto reset without using a boot and a reset button for native USB (USB CDC)? or would it always require a serial programming chip?

USB serial docs here
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c6_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#usbserialjtag
(Page 1000)
it looks like you just connect D+ and D- directly to usb data lines.

Some other ESP32 do not have in-built USB so you'd need to add a USB-UART bridge, and the transistors for boot and reset.
Here's one I prepared earlier.

You don't have to use CH340B - any other UART bridge with DTR and DTS available will work. I was using CP2102 but ran into the IC shortage.
The choice of transistor is not critical either any small NPN will work.
If you want reference schematics go to the Espressif site and download the ESP32-prog documentation. etc.

However, none of the chips on the market implement USB CDC. Each chip from any manufacturer implements a custom protocol that needs drivers to be installed or present in the system. For example this might be the reason some Arduinos use a 8-bit MCU as the target MCU but a far more powerful and advanced 32-bit MCU as the USB-UART bridge IC.

I must admit CDC is not a big selling point for me. If linux ships with drivers that's good enough for me.  That said any UART bridge can be used in the left part.

Thank you for the schematic and the answer. However, I am a bit confused with the Native USB support. According to the datasheet (https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c6_datasheet_en.pdf) ESP32-C6 has built in USB and support JTAG and Serial. Then why are you saying the chip has no USB (perhaps no CDC?)? Can the JTAG/Serial be used for USB programming ?

hmm , somehow I missed the in-built USB serial
